# What is the use of database table with only composite primary key, and nothing else?

Tags: sql, database, composite-primary-key

Just as the above question. Besides, this table's primary key is a foreign key in another tables, so what's the difference if we map them to their original tables without passing through this table's composite primary key?

Comment: Well perhaps this table is representing a subset of some other table.  More information would be helpful.

Comment: @DanMetheus Yes. There are other tables that references this table and adds another column to create its own composite primary key.

Comment: What does 'map them to their original tables without passing through this table's composite primary key' mean?

Comment: @EJP The composite key table A references different foreign keys in other tables Os, and from them it makes its composite primary key. Now, other tables Rs references this composite key table A. What is wrong if these tables Rs references foreign keys of Os directly without passing through A table?

Answer (score 0):

1) Without an integer primary key, performance will suffer for many tasks.

2) Many tools that automate code generation, require an integer primary key.